# Expression with last digits different

Tags: arithmetic

Given the expression:  $$1234567893 \times 1234567894 - 1234567895 \times1234567892$$
Is it correct to say that the answer is $ (3 \times 4) - (5 \times 2) $?
If so, why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

HINT :
$$(x+3)(x+4)-(x+5)(x+2)=3\times 4-5\times 2$$

Comment: Brilliant!      $\;$

Answer (score 7):

**Hint** $\ a\!+\!b = c\!+\!d\,\Rightarrow\, (x\!+\!a)(x\!+\!b)-(x\!+\!c)(x\!+\!d) = ab\!-\!cd,\ $ and conversely.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Let $a=123456789$.  Then your problem can be written as $(10a+3)(10a+4)-(10a+5)(10a+2)$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=1234567890$, then $(x+3)(x+4)-(x+2)(x+5)$. 
As $x$ terms get cancelled due to the sum of their last digits being equal, therefore answer can be obtained directly from their last digits.

Therefore....
$$(3*4)-(5*2)=2$$